# Slimbox 2 Plugin, jQuery Flickr, and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flickr, slimbox

I am currently developing a site that I make use of two jQuery plugins:

[jQuery Flickr plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-flickr/)

[jQuery Slimbox plugin](http://code.google.com/p/slimbox/)

The first plugin is used to pull in flickr photos from a specific account.  These photos are displayed as thumbnails on the page.  I am then using the second plugin to display larger views of these images.

Because the flickr photos are fetched when the page loads, I am calling the Slimbox2 function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Flickr").flickr(); //Call Flickr plugin
    $(window).bind('load', function() {
        $("#Flickr a").slimbox();//Call Slimbox2
    });
});
```

On first testing this seemed to have worked perfectly.  I tested multiple versions of FireFox, IE7, IE6, and Safari.  Everything is great.  However, the Slimbox lightbox effest does not work in IE8.  However, if I put IE8 into compatibility mode, everything works as expected.  I would like to avoid forcing compatibility mode.

There are no javascript errors and I am at a loss for testing.  Here is a link to a sample:

http://www.njhall.com/JRMcCourt-Builders/index.html#ourwork

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Any ideas as to why running IE8 in compatibility mode would change this?

Very strange to me.
Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having trouble with "$(window).bind('load', function() {" in IE8.  Basically, on the page I'm working on, it never fires in IE8.  Works fine in IE9, Firefox, Chrome, etc.  Just doesn't happen in IE8.

This is on a pretty complicated page (pulling in multiple jQuery plugins, ASP.NET ModalPopupExtenders, Facebook, Twitter, and YouTube stuff etc.), so I'm not sure exactly what might be getting in the way of IE8 firing the "load" function.

Not sure if this will help you at this point, but thought I'd post in case it does help someone at some point.